# Recursive Mapped Type

Tags: typescript

My goal is to build an API to mutate a nested, complex object.
A user should be allowed to either pass the new value directly or to use a operator-Function like append, delete, upsert.

I stuck by making this API type-safe.
I believe I need to recursively re-map the type respective object.

Yet, I was not able to implement the type correctly.

The code below shows an example

- What the given object is
- What the desired re-mapped type should look like
- How a final usage should look like

I am very thankful for every hint, advice or proposal.

**QUESTION**

How should the Type look like that maps `State` to `StateMutationSpec` (see code below)?

```js
// GIVEN: a complex object
interface State {
    a: { bs: number[], c: boolean}
}

// GIVEN: a general function that allows to mutate parts of the object or the object itself
type StateMutator<TState> = (state: TState) => TState;

// TARGET:
// 1. iterate over each member recursively 
// 2. specify and introduce an additional API in order to mutate the given object
interface StateMutationSpec {
    a : { 
        bs: number[]  | StateMutator<number[]> ,
        c: boolean | StateMutator<boolean> 
        } 
    | StateMutator<{ 
        bs: number[]  | StateMutator<number[]>, 
        c: boolean | StateMutator<boolean> 
    }>
}


// USAGE
const nextState: State = createNextState({
    a: patch({ bs: append(1), c: false })
});


function patch<T>(state: T):T {
    throw new Error("Not implemented");
}

function append<T>(state: ItemOf<T>): T {
    throw new Error("Not implemented")
}

function createNextState(mutator: StateMutationSpec): State {
    throw new Error("Not implemented")
}

type ItemOf<T> = T extends Array<infer TItem> ? TItem : never;
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9pjMw) meet your needs? Check against your use cases and if there's a problem, please [edit] the question to demonstrate any unsatisfied use cases.  If it works for you I can write up an answer explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a similar mapped type for deep merge operations:

```
export type DeepMergeSpec<T> = T extends DeepMergePrimitive | DeepMergeNully
  ? T
  : T extends Array<infer V>
  ? DeepMergeArray<V>
  : DeepMergeObject<T>;

type DeepMergePrimitive = boolean | string | number | symbol | bigint;
type DeepMergeNully = undefined | null;
type DeepMergeArray<T> = StateMutator<NonNullable<Array<T>>> | Array<T>;
type DeepMergeObject<T> = {
  readonly [K in keyof T]?:
    | DeepMergeSpec<T[K]>
    | StateMutator<NonNullable<T[K]>>;
};
```

You can generate your target type like this:

```
type StateMutationSpec = DeepMergeSpec<State>;
```

[Example TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/PTAEHEEkDUFEDkBcoCGoDGB7AtgBwDYCmAHqJgEYBWh6ALgFACWAdrYQE4BmK6hoAyrRRtQAb3qhJqZKNDkAzsmYBXbOQ4BtALoAaDMnKZMRFMwC%209C-RAQYCZGgDmhZhxT5QnZczqNMzUFoAC2FUfHxMAHd5QMxQbGUhEVwUdloYzE5AoL4KajoydmzcqhpaUEZ0wnxOeloAT1w%20QWFCAFlE4Ux2AB4AFRa2AD5QAF5QAAp5JMJkAZmASjGR%20daAbnprMD6AQQAlcFg%20xC3QAEYAOgq2dlayADcOUEIeIPjCNSf2GmV2eUZHvh6qBTgAmK7yJroRicYGmAAmFVY7Ew8OUvFQARQ8PhlT8zHcoB2AAVIEjCvCnrQ4gkZsVQI4AS4yKU6ExWBxuBjBu1OrR8fwoWIJFI0DIQVJJXJFKAVJ92NpJAAfAQzDpJbo9OXqBVaEY6EVS-RyIwmAIqnnqrq9QzGF7MEaGqVmCVSC1qvma2ROyUKJSqHWK0Du1pW6m9bWaPV6H1SdAGU324Oq0Oem2J0yOyVmIaWTY2UaFovFkulsvlov0Ei4brlBpNUAAEUIhFwbQ4zkFNH6I3GfWexDYzHhMWbrfb7GcxPYjGweMeybHbY7hHgynC9RFAH5QH0RXMB0OR0T2Ld6j0WJwntBc5Id0uJ84dqeUOeb-umy3l5PCAB5Vm0D2Gx1I0fAPiu06zvOfDjLaZrJtMM7MI4yaRkUKryPUajGMm5CMIyrAbPWYFfo%20q7rkCYygN4lKcCwhCIiqKjhERoGfuOK7PmePZUZaaY9PA-hruEKDkEQPRca%20PZDCMKqSeefRDKxDbgT%20-75IBilUeIkjfNi-iURoADS5IANaEPUmS7loW4nJKKqqZ2UL9MZepOiGbBhpqgnMMJ%20CieJfSuTJGxmMBIENnxSQClCoJUY5hBdugPQ8kp%20ZgBWmVZRWmzpaAACq-A7Ic9BYMw0yyiQtA8sgPJUegelsPAVU8hMOmisgKS0OgQRtdKDi4E0w4TGcCx6PGnjuPIfBmAslgLOFXg%20Py-igF1PU9lMMxzAsiD9u1kjBCikSVSdsCnt0EwAESCeUs4EB8LhsPCV0LXm9BLb4q0oINLjwpt0ytMgkBsNgv6cD2u27sKkpHVEp2gOdKLsNdt0VHgRDYE9DGve9n0rQEDUvE1LUzBMtLWrVHrRf4SWglDdUHdkx0I0jl03Zgd0Y49HIvXNVjEaAIMfODPF9oef0xPJF7MFeRR9ML2AjDuCug6ASiEI87BrEAA)